# How to Import data into Azure SQL database from Data Lake Storage Gen 1?

Tags: database, azure, import, ssms, azure-data-lake

I created an empty SQL database using Azure portal.
I also added some sample data to a data lake in Data Lake Storage Gen 1.
I downloaded SSMS, linked it to the server containing the SQL database, and added a new table using SSMS in order to have a target location to import the data into the SQL database.

Questions:  1.  Will the new table I added in SSMS be recognized in Azure?; 2. How do I get the sample data from the data lake I created into the new table I created in the Azure SQL database?

An article suggested using Azure HDInsight to transfer the data, but it's not part of my free subscription and I don't know how much charges I will incur using it.

Comment: Hi RAH, did you get any progresses? If the answer is helpful for you, could you think about  mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Will the new table I added in SSMS be recognized in Azure?**

Yes, when we connect to the Azure SQL database with [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15), all the operations in query editor will register/sync to the Azure SQL database. When the SQL statements executed/ran, we can refresh the SSMS and the new table will exist.

**How do I get the sample data from the data lake I created into the new table I created in the Azure SQL database?**

What's the sample data did you mean added to Data Lake Storage Gen 1, CSV files? If the file is not very large, I would suggest you download to you local computer can then using [SSMS Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15) to load the data to Azure SQL database. It may take some time, but it's free.
[image]

Or you may follow the tutorial [Copy data between Data Lake Storage Gen1 and Azure SQL Database using Sqoop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-transfer-sql-sqoop), I didn't find the price of Azure HDInsight when we create it. I'm not sure if it's free. I think you could try it.

Hope this helps.